# Most efficient way to calculate CRC16 in Python

Tags: python, numpy, crc16

I need to calculate CRC16 of binary numbers several times inside a loop. I have used the following method

```
import numpy as np
import binascii
#I have just filled the array with random numbers
#These arrays are loaded from a file
array1=np.random.randint(0,511, size=100000)
array2=np.random.randint(0,511, size=100000)
#...
#This goes on to till say array100
#Now calculate crc of each row in a loop
for j in range(100000):
    crc=0xffff
    #Convert the number to binary 16 bit format
    temp_bin=np.binary_repr(array1[j], 16)
    crc=binascii.crc_hqx(chr(int(temp_bin[0:8],2)), crc)
    crc=binascii.crc_hqx(chr(int(temp_bin[8:16],2)), crc)
    #Similarly for array2
    temp_bin=np.binary_repr(array2[j], 16)
    crc=binascii.crc_hqx(chr(int(temp_bin[0:8],2)), crc)
    crc=binascii.crc_hqx(chr(int(temp_bin[8:16],2)), crc)
    #...
    #This goes on till array100
```

While this method works perfectly, it is extremely slow. On profiling, I find converting each number to binary is the major bottleneck in my code.

Total time: 10.9712 s

File: speedup.py

Function: abc at line 7

Line _____       Hits  ____       Time  ____Per Hit ____  % Time  ____ Line Contents

```
 7                                           @profile
 8                                           def abc():
 9                                               #I have just filled the array with random numbers
10                                               #Thse arrays are loaded from a file
11         1       3269.0   3269.0      0.0      array1=np.random.randint(0,511, size=100000)
12         1       3206.0   3206.0      0.0      array2=np.random.randint(0,511, size=100000)
13                                               #...
14                                               #This goes on to till say array100
15                                               #Now calculate crc of each row in a loop
16    100001     237461.0      2.4      2.2      for j in range(100000):
17    100000     199887.0      2.0      1.8          crc=0xffff
18                                                   #Convert the number to binary 16 bit format
19    100000    3436116.0     34.4     31.3          temp_bin=np.binary_repr(array1[j], 16)
20    100000    1039049.0     10.4      9.5          crc=binascii.crc_hqx(chr(int(temp_bin[0:8],2)), crc)
21    100000     793751.0      7.9      7.2          crc=binascii.crc_hqx(chr(int(temp_bin[8:16],2)), crc)
22                                                   ##Similarly for array2
23    100000    3423862.0     34.2     31.2          temp_bin=np.binary_repr(array2[j], 16)
24    100000     991331.0      9.9      9.0          crc=binascii.crc_hqx(chr(int(temp_bin[0:8],2)), crc)
25    100000     843271.0      8.4      7.7          crc=binascii.crc_hqx(chr(int(temp_bin[8:16],2)), crc)
```

I have not been able to come up with an alternative solution that avoids it. So is there a more efficient and pythonic way to convert numbers to binary or to do this entire thing?

Comment: What are you using for the profiling?

Comment: @James I used line profiler .Here is the link https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler

Comment: I think something like this would work: `for row in np.column_stack((array1, array2, ..., array100)).astype('>u2'): row_crc = crc_hqx(row, 0xffff)`. I.e. you don't have to loop byte by byte, the `crc_hqx` function can do that for you. The tricky thing for this to work is to have the data in big-endian format, hence `.astype('>u2')`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you can probably bypass sending the interger to string and back.  Especially since you are padding a 8-bit binary array to 16 bits with zeros, only to split it in half again.  Instead, try:

```
zb = np.zeros(1, dtype=np.uint8)[0].tobytes()
for j in range(100000):
    crc=0xffff
    tmp_data = array1[j].tobytes()
    crc=binascii.crc_hqx(zb, crc)
    crc=binascii.crc_hqx(tmp_data, crc)

    tmp_data = array2[j].tobytes()
    crc=binascii.crc_hqx(zb, crc)
    crc=binascii.crc_hqx(tmp_data, crc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out a faster way. Instead of converting the number to binary in the first place we can just use bit operators cleverly. This implementation is about thrice as fast.

```
import numpy as np
import binascii
#I have just filled the array with random numbers
#These arrays are loaded from a file
array1=np.random.randint(0,511, size=100000)
array2=np.random.randint(0,511, size=100000)
#...
#This goes on to till say array100
#Now calculate crc of each row in a loop
for j in range(100000):
    crc=0xffff
    #Convert the number to binary 16 bit format
    crc=binascii.crc_hqx(chr(array1[j] >> 8), crc)
    crc=binascii.crc_hqx(chr(array1[j] & 255), crc)
    #Similarly for array2
    crc=binascii.crc_hqx(chr(array2[j] >> 8), crc)
    crc=binascii.crc_hqx(chr(array2[j] & 255), crc)
    #...
    #This goes on till array100
```

Comparison using line profiler shows that this method calculating CRC is more than thrice as fast:

Total time: 2.66351 s

File: speedup1.py

Function: abc at line 4

## Line__  Hits  __       Time  __Per Hit _  % Time ____ Line Contents

```
 4                                           @profile
 5                                           def abc():
 6                                               #I have just filled the array with random numbers
 7                                               #These arrays are loaded from a file
 8         1       1204.0   1204.0      0.0      array1=np.random.randint(0,511, size=100000)
 9         1       1207.0   1207.0      0.0      array2=np.random.randint(0,511, size=100000)
10                                               #...
11                                               #This goes on to till say array100
12                                               #Now calculate crc of each row in a loop
13    100001      93020.0      0.9      3.5      for j in range(100000):
14    100000      83277.0      0.8      3.1          crc=0xffff
15                                                   #Convert the number to binary 16 bit format(This is the old method)
16    100000    1280059.0     12.8     48.1          temp_bin=np.binary_repr(array1[j], 16)
17    100000     351190.0      3.5     13.2          crc=binascii.crc_hqx(chr(array1[j] >> 8), crc)
18    100000     299711.0      3.0     11.3          crc=binascii.crc_hqx(chr(array1[j] & 255), crc)
19                                                   #Similarly for array2(This is the new method using bit operators)
20    100000     276893.0      2.8     10.4          crc=binascii.crc_hqx(chr(array2[j] >> 8), crc)
21    100000     276946.0      2.8     10.4          crc=binascii.crc_hqx(chr(array2[j] & 255), crc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [crcmod](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/crcmod). It will generate efficient code for the specified CRC.

Comment: I just checked, binascii.crc is a tad bit faster than crcmod in this case. Plus my main bottleneck was converting each individual number to binary format.

Comment: Though only if that one happens to be the 16-bit CRC you need.